# Login authentication asp.net with active directory

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, authentication, active-directory

i have a project where i need to use the active directory for login to a website made in asp.net, i follow this tutorial....

[Active Directory Authentication from ASP .NET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180890%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

now i want to get the groups of the user, i tried the next code in the default.aspx.vb page but doesn't work..

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    Response.Write("Hello, " + Server.HtmlEncode(User.Identity.Name))

    Dim id As FormsIdentity = CType(User.Identity, FormsIdentity)

    If id IsNot Nothing Then

        Dim ticket As FormsAuthenticationTicket = id.Ticket
        Response.Write("<p/>TicketName: " + ticket.Name)
        Response.Write("<br/>Cookie Path: " + ticket.CookiePath)
        Response.Write("<br/>Ticket Expiration: " + ticket.Expiration.ToString())
        Response.Write("<br/>Expired: " + ticket.Expired.ToString())
        Response.Write("<br/>Persistent: " + ticket.IsPersistent.ToString())
        Response.Write("<br/>IssueDate: " + ticket.IssueDate.ToString())
        Response.Write("<br/>UserData: " + ticket.UserData)
        Response.Write("<br/>Version: " + ticket.Version.ToString())
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Please specify what isn't working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I find a better solution, is more easy than any answer that i find on the internet.

First i create a class to validate if an user is in a group in the active directory:

```
Imports System.Security.Principal   

Public Class AutorizationFun
    Dim access As Boolean = False
    Dim id As WindowsIdentity = WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent()
    Public User As WindowsPrincipal = New WindowsPrincipal(id)
```

## Region "Groups Verification"

```
'Belongs to sample group
Private Function inSampleGroup() As Boolean
    Return User.IsInRole("bth0\GG BTUC-SAMPLEGROUP")
End Function
Private Function inSampleGroup2() As Boolean
    Return User.IsInRole("bth0\GG BTUC-SAMPLEGROUP2")
End Function
```

## End Region

```
Public Function ProgramsAccsess(ByVal vPage As String) As Boolean
    access = False

    Select Case vPage
        Case "~/Sample.aspx"
            If inSampleGroup() Then
                access = True
            End If
        '---------------------------------------------------------------------
    End Select
    '*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*
    'access = True
    '*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*
    Return access
End Function   

End Class
```

Then you have to create a function in the code behind of all pages:

```
'create var
    Dim ValidateUser As New AutorizationFun

    Protected Sub VerifyAccessPage()
        If ValidateUser.ProgramsAccsess(Request.AppRelativeCurrentExecutionFilePath) = False Then
            Response.Redirect("~/DeniedAccess.aspx")
        End If
    End Sub
```

And to finish to have to use the function in the Page_load event:

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        'check whether page is postback or not            
        If Not Page.IsPostBack Then
            VerifyAccessPage()
        End If
    End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

If your server is in a Windows Domain it should be connected to Active Directory, so by using windows authentication you already login with AD credentials (since the user has to be in the domain before, or it will be asked for AD credentials by the browser)

To get the user groups you could use the [DirectorySearcher](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.directorysearcher.aspx) class, obviously when you